# Общая переменная прогресса для 3х последовательных полос прогресса

Tags: javascript

x это текущий общий прогресс

y это максимальный прогресс

z это текущий отдел

---

x = растет постепенно (к примеру по 10 в секунду)

y = 100 * (количество отделов)

z = нумерация отдела

---

Возмем на примере 3 отдела каждый по 100% в итоге получаем 300

X растет по 10 а значит каждый отдел будет заполняться по 10 секунд

Не могу сделать функцию которая принимая X Y Z будет возращать прогресс нужного нам отдела...

вот примеры параметров и ответ который должен получиться

x=27  y=300 z=1 Ответ = 27%

x=105 y=300 z=1 Ответ = 100%

x=150 y=300 z=2 Ответ = 50%

x=201 y=300 z=2 Ответ = 100%

x=201 y=300 z=3 Ответ = 1%

Буду очень благодарен Вам за помощь, никак не могу адекватно реализовать функцию хоть понимаю что не особо и сложно...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
console.log( bubu( 27, 300, 1) ); // 27
console.log( bubu(105, 300, 1) ); // 100
console.log( bubu(150, 300, 2) ); // 50
console.log( bubu(201, 300, 2) ); // 100
console.log( bubu(201, 300, 3) ); // 1

console.log( bubu( 27, 300, 2) ); // 0
console.log( bubu( 200, 300, 2) ); // 100

function bubu(x, y, z) {  
  z *= 100;
  return ( z - 100 < x && x < z ) ? ( x % 100 ) : 100 * ( x >= z )
}
```

`100 * ( x >= z )` :

- 100 * true → 100 * 1 → 100
- 100 * false → 100 * 0 → 0

Comment: немного модернизировал ваш вариант чтоб он мог выдавать 0% если я спрашиваю отдел до которого прогресс не дощел =) ``getProcess = (x, y, z) => (x >= z * y ? y : x < (z * y) - y ? 0 : x % y) + '%';``

Comment: @РагнарЛодброк Чу-то ваше выражение не проходит тесты) Тоже обновил ответ* `y` кстати не участвует в расчетах...

Comment: да, я заменил значение "y" теперь равняется 100 ( кололичество одного отдела ). У меня работает отлично   getProcess( 90, 100, 3)   ответ будет 0

Answer (score 1):

Примерно так:

```
const rawProgress = x - (z - 1) * 100
const progress = rawProgress > 100 ? 100 : rawProgress
```